# Iterate and managing files with batch in network route vs local route

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I run my code by inserting this lines to my window explorer address bar. It iterates all the files in the selected directory (just with the desired extensions specified in the list). It renames the files by adding a sequential number then append to fajlnevek to be able to paste it from the clipboard at the end. It also moves the renamed files to a new directory. **I don't understand why it does not work if I change the path from network route to my simple local.**

**It works with this kind of network routes:**

```
\\something.ab.lol.aa\MakroModul\teszt.bat "\\something.ab.lol.aa\Datenimport_Edge" "\\something.ab.lol.aa\folder" FILENAME
```

**..but it doesn't work with my local route:**

```
C:\Users\ABC\Name, My Name(A B-C44) - 990_BACKUP\\teszt.bat "C:\Temp\test\from" "C:\Temp\test\to" FILENAME
```

**The code:**

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set/a fileNum = 1

chcp 28591

set arg1=%~1
set arg2=%~2
set arg3=%~3

mkdir "%arg2%"

set list=txt csv xls pdf doc ppt
set fajlnevek=

for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
for %%f in (%arg1%\*.%%a) do (
  
  echo %arg3%_!fileNum!%%~xf
  echo "%%~nf%%~xf"

  ren %arg1%\"%%~nf%%~xf" %arg3%_!fileNum!%%~xf

  if .!fajlnevek!==. (
    set fajlnevek=%arg2%\%arg3%_!fileNum!%%~xf
) else (
    set fajlnevek=!fajlnevek!,%arg2%\%arg3%_!fileNum!%%~xf
)
  
  set/a fileNum += 1
)
  move "%arg1%\*.%%a" "%arg2%"
)

echo %fajlnevek% | clip
pause

(arg first from place
arg second to place
third arg new file name
```

Comment: Bad quotation! Use the quoted syntax `set "VAR=Value"`, which protects special characters but does not include the quotes in the value. Quote full paths like `"%ROOT%\subdir\file.ext"`. Then replace `if .!VAR!==.` by `if "!VAR!"==""`, or even better, `if not defined VAR`…

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl! Could you maybe make a new code snipet here with the correct answer? I've tried to manage it with the quoted syntax but didn't really work - maybe I missed something.